# Distribution of the sum of two squared independent r.v.

Tags: normal-distribution, self-learning, independence, chi-squared

I have to give the distribution of $Z_1^2 + Z_2^2$ knowing that $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent standard normal variables.

I've found that $Z_1^2 + Z_2^2$ it is typically Chi-squared distributed and hence it's easy to find it's cdf on the internet, but I fear that I'm missing the core of the answer. Would it be sufficient to say : "Well it is Chi-squared distributed, if you look in your book the cdf of that distribution is this one. The end" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate $P(Z_1^2+Z_2^2\le z)$, using the normal density function, then switch to the polar coordinates ( you will integrate on the disc of radius$\sqrt{z}$, and center(0,0)), finally you will get 
$P(Z_1^2+Z_2^2\le z)=e^{-0.5z}$, which is the cdf of a chi-squared distribution with d=2

More details :
F is the cdf of $Z_1^2+Z_2^2$
$F(z)=P(Z_1^2+Z_2^2\le z)=\int_{\mathbb{R^2}}{1_{\{z_1^2+z_2^2\leq z\}}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}{(z_1^2+z_2^2)}}dz_1dz_2}$

By changing the coordinates

$=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{\sqrt{z}}{e^{-\frac{1}{2}{r^2}}rdrd\theta}}$

Integrating $\theta$ first and finally r, we have the result wanted

Comment: I added details in the answer. Why are you changing the sign of the inequality ? Also , the formula you wrote seems to be wrong. 
Let X a real random variable and its density function f. If we take g a function ,
$E(g(X))=\int_{\mathbb{R}}{g(x)f(x)dx}$. In particular, for a given real c, $P(X\leq c)=E(1_{X\leq c})=\int_{\mathbb{R}}{1_{x\leq c}f(x)dx}$

Comment: Alright. I see your point. What does the numbers you put between bracket at the bottom of $1$ mean ? The $θ=2π$ it is because it can be in the four cadran because of the square am I right ?

Comment: It is the indicator function : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Comment: Alright equal to one for every value smaller or equal to c. For me the pdf should end with $exp(-x^2/2)$. I don't see where the minus went.

Comment: It is a typo, but it does not change the final result

Comment: You did an amazing job explaining me all that in simple terms. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49321/discussion-between-endlessend2525-and-canardini).